# Is it okay to post products and ask which one is better?

Tags: discussion

I want to buy a violin and there's none to advise me. I searched through the Internet. Read a lot and concluded on some products. Is it okay if I post them and ask for an opinion? They are online products. I'm desperate for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid not - this site is not a comparison site or a shopping recommendation site. In fact we have that as an explicit close reason in our off topic section. Please read our help pages for info.

Comment: can you recommend some forum to ask help?

Comment: I'd probably go to google, but realistically, if you are buying over the internet, the most important thing is how much you trust the seller. Not much point getting people to opine on pictures or descriptions without seeing the instrument in person, as they could be faked. The few instruments I have bought online, I made sure I had a no quibble return policy.

Comment: I want to know which violin produces better sound. I am a beginner and don't trust my judgment. Is there any forum where I can ask them providing some demo videos of the products?

Comment: I don't know - google is a much better place to search for that sort of thing.

Comment: @noobmaster69 You can always word and shape your question to something that will be useful to many, like talk about woods, tone, action, materials, etc. Simply asking "which brand is better" is subjective and not very useful, but specific objective sound and music dynamics are the actual important part of your choice, and can be very useful to future readers.

Comment: @noobmaster69 try YouTube videos instead for violin reviews. You might also stumble upon "interesting" videos demonstrating the difference between cheap violins and expensive violins, in which you might not even hear/distinguish the difference.